# HighCharts iOS Wrapper: Drilldown Events are getting triggered but properties are nil

Tags: ios, highcharts, wrapper

I am having trouble with the following code I am trying to get "category" or any other property possible on the drill-down event but that is not happening. I get the event but the properties are "nil" in all of the cases.

Following is my code

```
let event = HIEvents()
event.drilldown = HIFunction(closure: { [weak self] x in

   print(x?.getProperty("this.category"), x?.getProperty("this.seriesOptions"), x?.getProperty("this.point"), x?.getProperty("this.event.xAxis[0].value"))

},properties: ["this.category", "this.seriesOptions", "this.point", "this.event.xAxis[0].value"])

chart.events = event
```

Its is not just this event other events on "plotoption->series->point" are giving "nil" for properties in most of the cases as well.

What I eventually want to achieve is dynamic minWidth on different levels of drill-down depending on the number of categories on the xAxis

```
chart.scrollablePlotArea = HIScrollablePlotArea()
chart.scrollablePlotArea.minWidth = width
```

**Solution:**

> the drill-down event has `event` context instead of `this`.

So, I needed to get the properties in the following way:

```
let event = HIEvents()
event.drilldown = HIFunction(closure: { [weak self] x in

   print(x?.getProperty("event.category"), x?.getProperty("event.seriesOptions"), x?.getProperty("event.point.x"), x?.getProperty("event.point.y"))

},properties: ["event.category", "event.seriesOptions", "event.point.x", "event.point.y"])

chart.events = event
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Hunble Dhillon, I see that you have already opened an issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-ios/issues/218 This case will be continue on github.

Comment: Okay, thanks btw can you add a tag with "highCharts-ios-wrapper" or something alike? and should I delete this question from here?

Comment: It is ok to use `highcharts` tag. You can delete this question, but it is not a must.